# How would you construct a holomorphic function with a prescribed argument?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I wanted to construct a holomorphic function with a given complex argument, but don't care about its modulus. What are the restrictions on my prescribed argument so that I could do such a thing?

To be more precise, I would like to construct a holomorphic function $F$ such as
$$
F(z) = f(u,v)\exp(i\arg(u,v)),
$$
where $z=u+iv$, $f$ is a (real-valued) modulus and arg is my desired argument.

If we attempt to solve for $f$, the Cauchy-Riemann equations read:
$$
f_u\cos(\arg) - f\sin(\arg)\arg_u = f_v\sin(\arg) + f\cos(\arg)\arg_v
$$
$$
f_v\cos(\arg) - f\sin(\arg)\arg_v = -f_u\sin(\arg) - f\cos(\arg)\arg_u
$$

I'm currently unable to solve this system of PDEs for even the simplest of cases. In fact, it's not clear if a solution even generally exists.

So, the question: are there are any well-known theorems on how to construct analytical functions with a prescribed argument/modulus? If so, to what extent can we do it?

Comment: $\arg(u,v)$ needs to be harmonic (at least on an open dense set of your domain) since $\log F$ is locally holomorphic where non zero and you can define a logarithm $\log F=\log f+i \arg(u,v)$ locally around any point where $F$ is non zero and those points are of course dense (actually their complement must be discrete) to have a non trivial solution; even if $\arg (u,v)$ is harmonic, you may not have a global $F$ unless you are on a simply connected domain, but that depends on the situation